# MySQL max() followed by ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I'm working with a MySql table. The table contains numeric values and unix date values only.  Each row has a unique id, columns containing ids related to other parts of the db, totals (like downloads per day) and the date that the row was inserted. My queries need to get the latest date for each id combination, in order to get the downloads for that day. One row is inserted each day for each id combination, and the index spans all of the ids and the date.

I have found through testing that it is quicker to perform two queries to get the exact row I want under certain circumstances. I would like a second opinion about this.

Here is a scenario that is very fast and uses the index:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1 AND mydate BETWEEN 123456789 AND 134567890 ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 1`

(The index is A, B, mydate)

Here is one that is very slow and doesn't use the index:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE A IN (1, 2) AND B = 1 AND mydate BETWEEN 123456789 AND 134567890 GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY mydate DESC`

This returns the correct result but doesn't use the index and is very slow.  In reality, this simple example might use the index, but something like `A IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....10000) AND B IN (1,2,3,4,5,... 10000)` doesn't, and that's what I need to cater for.

Here is where it gets interesting.

The following uses the index and is very fast:

`SELECT *, MAX(mydate) FROM foo WHERE A IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....10000) AND B IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....10000) AND mydate BETWEEN 123456789 AND 134567890 GROUP BY A, B`

The rows returned contain each unique combination of ids and the MAX of `mydate` for each combination. But, the row returned for each combination isn't necessarily the one with the corresponding `MAX(mydate)`, and therefore does not necessarily give the correct downloads of that day. The `MAX` value is the correct value for that specific combination though, so my second query can be specific and use the index. Assuming A was 1, B was 1 and the `MAX(mydate)` equalled 1235555555 for that specific id combination, then I can execute

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE A = 1 AND B = 1 AND mydate = 1235555555`

This second query returns the specific row I want, uses the index and is therefore fast.

I do have to do a `foreach` with php, so there's a processing overhead there, but it's still significantly quicker than trying to get MySQL to do all the work.

Another benefit is that all of these simple queries execute as seperate MySQL processes.

It just doesn't feel right, am I missing something?

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY A, B` only seems to work correctly. Apart from the values for columns `A` and `B`, all the other values selected by `*` are random values picked from the corresponding columns. It happens that, if you don't delete rows from the table, the returned values belong to the first (i.e. the oldest) row from each group but this is not contractual. It just happen to work this way on the existing MySQL versions, it can change anytime.

Comment: @axiac . . . They are not "random", they are *indeterminate*.  But your comment is basically correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right, [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is the correct word for what happens there.